# 504 Gateway timeout when using Azure Service Bus Relay to serve static files

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I am serving static files (a web page) over a wcf azure relay, but one (or more) of the js files will return 504 gateway timeout, and the html page takes a while to load. However, **there were no issues** when serving the files directly through a port on the server. Will changing the  [ReceiveTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) or [SendTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.sendtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) on the [Web​Http​Relay​Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.webhttprelaybinding?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0) have any effect on this, or could it be something else related to the wcf configuration? If not, is there any other way to troubleshoot this problem?

I can post some more code if needed but the setup for the wcf connection is similar (but slightly different) to the wcf relay sample (https://github.com/Azure/azure-relay/blob/master/samples/WCF%20Relay/RelayHttpNoAuth/Service/Program.cs):

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    GetType(),
    new WebHttpRelayBinding(
        EndToEndWebHttpSecurityMode.None,
        RelayClientAuthenticationType.None) {IsDynamic = true},
    httpAddress)
    .EndpointBehaviors.Add(
        new TransportClientEndpointBehavior(
            TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(listenToken)));

host.Open();
```

**Edit:**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311276/5335355) ended up being the cause of why the requests were timing out. It really wasn't directly related to Azure Service Bus at all.

Comment: I checked the git sample, but did not reproduce your issue. Could you provide a simple project for us to reproduce this issue?

Comment: It is going to be hard to do that, because the behavior I described is only happening at 1 site.